# MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Reinstalled High Sierra but cannot login the iCloud account

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, high-sierra

I have a  MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) and I found the MacBook has been very slow after upgrading to Big Sur. Many people suggested downgrading to High Sierra and I reinstalled High Sierra. The machine is much faster, however, I cannot log in to the iCloud (as shown below), the App Store and even cannot install XCode.

[image]

[image]

I tried many methods, however, currently, there is no workaround to address this issue.

Comment: Can you log in to icloud.com or with the same account on a different device (to eliminate an access issue with the account)?

Comment: @fsb Yes, I can.

Comment: Do you have two-factor authentication turned on for your iCloud ID?

Comment: @fsb Yes. I turned it on on my iPhone: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915. On my current MacBook, I cannot turn it on as I should log in to the iCloud. I have MacBook Pro M1, maybe I can turn it on on that machine.

Comment: I'd guess you'll need to update to Mojave at least to regain the functionality. There are a great many bugs [that will never be fixed] in HS & earlier, resulting in inability to correctly work with the App Store. You can get Mojave direct - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Comment: This might have something to do with 2FA.  Are you receiving the 2FA code on your other devices?

Comment: @fsb Yes. I received.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think maybe that is the reason.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I installed Mojave and there is no issue now.